# Lost my key for signing Android App bundle

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have lost my signing key and then switched to App Signing by Google but still I am getting the same response that my keys are invalid.

Comment: Did you lose your signing key before or after switching to App Signing by Google?  If after, you just need to follow the lose key instructions. If before, switching won't help you-  you need to original key to switch.

Comment: I lost my signing key before switching.

Comment: Then there's only two options.  Create a new listing, with a new key, which you'd need to get existing users to switch to to get updates.  Or you can try to contact Google and see if they can reset the listing to a new key-  but any old users would need to uninstall and reinstall to get updates (and Google may no longer do this, it was their solution before App Signing).  There's no way to fix a lost key if you didn't already have app signing turned on.